# Cannot read property 'map' when not using conditional rendering in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to render this code, I got an error when `.map()` the dates. (line50):

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

After I use conditional rendering `{dates && dates.map((item) => <DateItem item={item} />)}`
the render succeeded.
The thing I don't understand is why should I use to use dates.
When I render just line47 and line48, I don't need to use conditional rendering.
Is it a problem of rendering speed?
If I use conditional rendering, when the dates state is made?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const DateItem = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{item.day}</div>
      <div>{item.date}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Dates = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState();
  const [day, setDay] = useState();
  const [dates, setDates] = useState();

  const getDateArr = () => {
    let arr = [];
    var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0] = "sunday";
    weekday[1] = "monday";
    weekday[2] = "tuesday";
    weekday[3] = "wednesday";
    weekday[4] = "thursday";
    weekday[5] = "friday";
    weekday[6] = "saturday";
    for (let i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
      let d = new Date();
      d.setDate(d.getDate() - i);
      let date = d.getDate();
      let day = weekday[d.getDay()];
      arr.push({ day, date });
    }
    // console.log(arr);
    return arr;
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    setDate(new Date().getFullYear());
    setDay(new Date().getMonth());
    setDates(getDateArr());
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="dateSection">
        <div className="head">날짜</div>
        <div className="year">{date}</div>  // line47
        <div className="month">{day}</div>
        <div className="dates">
          {dates.map((item) => (        // <=error line50
            <DateItem item={item} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Dates;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `.map()` can only be called on arrays. Also `setDates` is happening **asynchronously** and that's why you have `undefined` value in `dates` on the first render in your component. For `dates` with `useState([])` you can setup default empty array value. Or you can test `dates` if it has value other then `null` or `undefined` with `&&`.

Try the following:

```
const [dates, setDates] = useState([]);
```

Or check for `null` or `undefined` values:

```
{dates && dates.map((item) => (
   <DateItem item={item} />
))}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I forgot basic things. Your answer is really helpful.Thank you.

Comment: @dev_jeong It's fine, that's why we have this community to help each other. If the solution works for you, please consider upvoting and accepting as the answer for your question, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This happening as `dates` is set to `undefined` as nothing is passed to `useState()` as default value at start. You can easily fix this by passing an empty array `[]` as an initial value like:

```
const [dates, setDates] = useState([]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.I need to write down this.